# Last modified Time file list in aws s3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have multiple keys under my aws s3 bucket.
The structure is :

**bucket/tableName1/Archive/archive1.json -*to*- bucket/tableName1/Archive/archiveN.json
bucket/tableName2/Archive/archive2.json -*to*- bucket/tableName2/Archive/archiveN.json
bucket/tableName1/Audit/audit1.json -*to*- bucket/tableName1/Audit/auditN.json
bucket/tableName2/Audit/audit2.json -*to*- bucket/tableName2/Audit/auditN.json**

I want to get the keys from the **Audit folder** only if it is present in a key and get only the the latest file i.e. which has the last modified time as most recent from that Audit folder.

The result that I am trying to get is a list of dictionary :

**[{'tableName1' : 'auditN.json'}, {'tableName2' : 'auditN.json'}]**

Assuming **auditN.json** is the newest file.

I tried different methods but i am not getting the desired result.I am trying the  solution on databricks notebook.
Is there a way that I can achieve this ?

Comment: Keep it simple, you want to get the last modified file from folder using boto3 ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I don't think so. Given files on S3 with path bucket/xxx/yyy/zzz.json, for all the possible variants off xxx get the name of the last modified file from the xxx/Audit folder. It's not clear whether the possible variants of xxx are fixed.

Comment: can you please add more inforamtion? your question is not clear..

Comment: @AmitBaranes for multiple table names inside aws s3 bucket i have archive and audit folder and each of these have different files. So first I want to filter out only the Audit folder and then for each of the table names inside Audit folder, i want to fetch last modified time for the latest/ newest file for every table name using boto3.

Comment: @redbirdo xxx as you said is the tablename and yyy is the Audit/Archive folder and inside this Audit/Archive folder i have multiple files. So i have to filter out the Audit folder first for each tablename and then get only one file each for the tablename which is the latest/newest file.

Comment: So just to make sure i understand, you want to iterate over folder, get each subfolder and the last modified file inside of it?

Comment: @AmitBaranes yes correct , for every folder which has Audit as subfolder

Comment: Ok, I'll try to work about something later on today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've been reading and searching over a lot of threads about what you're asking but no luck. So, I had to write my own lambda function.

The following code snippet iterate over all folders, then iterate over the subfolders check if the subfolder name ==  Audit, if it does- sort by last modified and print the newest object.

**Be aware that this code fits your structure only! since `list_folders` function return only the first subfolders.**

In case your structure changed to something like that:

```
bucket/tableName1/Audit/Audit1/audit.json
```

The lambda won't work.

Code snippet :

```
import boto3

#bucket Name
bucket_name = 'Bucket Name'
#bucket Resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

#bucket client
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

#filter pattern 
get_last_modified = lambda obj: int(obj.last_modified.strftime('%s'))

#get subfolder - 1 LEVEL ONLY ! 
def list_folders(s3_client, bucket_name,prefix):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name,Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')
    for content in response.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
        yield content.get('Prefix')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #get all folders 
    folder_list = list_folders(s3_client, bucket_name,'')
    for folder in folder_list:
        #get all subfolders
        subfolders =  list_folders(s3_client, bucket_name,folder)
        for subfolder in subfolders:
            #iterate over subfolders and check if subfolder name equal to Audit
            if 'Audit' == subfolder.split('/')[1]:
                #get all objects under subfolder
                objs = [obj for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= subfolder)]
                #sort by last modified by filter pattern and get the first object 
                last_modified_file = [obj for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)][-1]
                #print results
                print('Last modified file Name: %s ---- Date: %s' % (last_modified_file.key,last_modified_file.last_modified))
```

Tested against the following files:
[image]

**`Table2` subfolder named `Archive`.**
[image]

[image]

Output :

[image]

Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Comment: I just notice you tagged python 3 and my lambda function wrote with python 2.7, so some small changes might be needed.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, not an issue.